# Error in processing request Error code: 200 Error text: OK (rejected) - WAMP server

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I was recently trying to login into my PhpMyAdmin panel in my WAMP server(localhost) and I got the following error

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK (rejected)
It seems that the connection to the server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

I'm using:
PHP: 7.1.33
PhpMyAdmin: 5.0.2
MariaDB: 10.3.23

[image]

and here is my config.inc.php:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;
/* The 'cookie' auth_type uses AES algorithm to encrypt the password. If
 * at least one server configuration uses 'cookie' auth_type, enter here a
 * pass phrase that will be used by AES. The minimum length is 32 characters
 * The maximum length seems to be 46 characters. */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'h]C+{nqW$omNoTIkCwC$%z-LTcy%p6_j';

//Checking Active DBMS Servers
$wampConf = @parse_ini_file('../../wampmanager.conf');
//Check if MySQL and MariaDB with MariaDB on default port
$mariaFirst = ($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on' && $wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] == 'on' && $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'] == $wampConf['mysqlDefaultPort']) ? true : false;
if($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on') {
/* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
}
/* Server: localhost [2] */
if($wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] =='on') {
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i -= 2;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MariaDB';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';
    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
}

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
/* End of servers configuration */

?>
```

I tried clearing all cookies and refreshing the webpage, and the "allow all cookies fix". I tried it in other browsers too but the error was still there. I also tried reinstalling all service but still left with the same error.
Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: Could you please tell us which MariaDB, PHP, and phpMyAdmin versions you are using?

Comment: PHP: 7.1.33
PhpMyAdmin: 5.0.2
MariaDB: 10.3.23

Comment: That's really strange because the error message suggests a very old MariaDB version (I'm having trouble find exactly when `lc_messages` was introduced, but it was probably around version 5.1 or 5.5). But your MariaDB 10.3 should have support for it, and I haven't the foggiest idea why it wouldn't be working properly. Is there any chance you have another MySQL or MariaDB server instance running on the server that isn't the one you expect? Perhaps you can look in your operating system process list to see the full path of the running instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, today I finally fixed it and I guess it was due to the Anti-Virus update(I'm not sure). I installed Bitdefender and WAMP did work after the installation but after some days this error started to show up. To fix this I uninstalled WAMP and disabled my Anti-Virus and installed WAMP Server Again. Now it works perfectly! Hope it helps :)